# How to perform a binding inside the calling of a converter in WPF XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, converters

This should be very simple, but I can't find it. Currently, I have the following trigger:

```
<DataTrigger 
  Binding="{Binding warmed,
            Converter={converters:IsGreaterThan 185}}"
  Value="False">
```

As you can see, there is a comparison to a fix value (185), but I'd like this to be variable, so I tried something like this:

```
<DataTrigger
  Binding="{Binding warmed,
           Converter={converters:IsGreaterThan 
                      "{Binding MaxMinutes}"
                     }
           }"
  Value="False">
```

(I've added some whitespace for readability reasons.

Although this should be extremely simple, I don't seem to find it.

I tried to convert my situation in a situation, using such a `ConverterParameter`, but no success:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding warmed, 
                       Converter={converters:IsGreaterThan}, 
                       ConverterParameter=185}"
             Value="False">
```

This seems not to work. How can I convert my situation in one, using a `ConverterParameter`?

When opening the "Create Data Binding" dialog box, this is what I see:

[image]

As you can see, no trace of that value 185, although it is crucial in my solution. When I fill it in as the `ConverterParameter`, this is what I get:

```
<DataTrigger
    Binding="{Binding warmed,
            ConverterParameter=185,
            Converter={converters:IsGreaterThan 185}}"
    Value="False">
```

... and again no way to declare any multibinding (as I couldn't get it done by trying to type it, I tried to get it using the Visual Studio "Properties" editor).

### Edit: a new attempt

Again a try, this time trying to introduce the `MultiBinding`:

```
<DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding>
            <Binding Path="warmed"/>
            <Binding Converter="{converters:IsGreaterThan 185}"/>
            <Binding Value="False"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
```

It yields two error messages:

> XLS0413 : The property 'Value' was not found in type 'Binding'.
> XDG0012 : The member "Value" is not recognised or is not accessible.

Comment: You can neither bind the ConverterParameter nor anything else inside a Binding. So the answer is still: use a MultiBinding.

Comment: @Clemens: how? I tried replacing the first `Binding` by `MultiBinding`, the second, both, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are correct that it's not possible to directly use a `ConverterParameter` with a variable using pure XAML. XAML is just inflexible that way.

While a `MultiBinding` could be made to work here, I think it's a risky approach (more on that later) and certainly overkill. Instead I would simply handle this at the view model level by defining a `bool` POCO property `WarmEnough` whose value is derived from `Warmed` and `MaxMinutes`:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool WarmEnough => this.Warmed >= this.MaxMinutes;

    private double _warmed;
    public double Warmed
    {
        get
        {
            return _warmed;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_warmed == value)
                return;
            _warmed = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WarmEnough));
        }
    }

    private double _MaxMinutes;
    public double MaxMinutes
    {
        get
        {
            return _MaxMinutes;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_MaxMinutes == value)
                return;
            _MaxMinutes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WarmEnough));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? name = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Then you simply bind your trigger to the `WarmEnough` property without regard to converters and the like. (Just make sure you don't need a two-way binding for some reason!) This works because a property change is raised for `WarmEnough` whenever `Warmed` or `MaxMinutes` are changed. So the `Trigger` will be, er, triggered, whenever either of those properties is changed.

Functionally it's the same as a `MultiBinding` - inside the `Convert` method of the `IMultiValueConverter` you'd basically do the same thing I'm suggesting you do in the getter of `WarmEnough` - but the problem is the values will come into the multi-converter as an array of `object`s, whose types you'll need to check and cast, and which will depend on the order of the `Binding`s in the XAML. This could easily trip up future you and/or your successors without explicit documentation. IMO `MultiBinding` is really best suited for situations when all the values are the same type and the correct order is either obvious or irrelevant, such as doing boolean AND/OR/XOR checks on multiple conditions, concatenating strings together, etc. Of course it could be done this way so perhaps Clemens will be kind enough to show us. But I would stick with the view model based approach and short circuit all of this.

Answer (score 1):

`Value`is a property of the `DataTrigger` and not `Binding`. To fix your XAML just set the property on the correct object (`DataTrigger`). Next, feed in all the data that is required to return `true` or `false` i.e. to create the condition using the `MultiBinding`.

You didn't post any useful information only snippets without context so you have to figure out the details yourself:

**TemperatureLimitConverter.cs**

```cs
class TemperatureLimitConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert (object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    double maxMinutes = values.OfType<double>().First();
    bool temperature = values.OfType<double>().Last();

    // Return the boolean that will be evaluated by the DataTrigger
    return temperature > maxMinutes;
  }
    
  public object[] ConvertBack (object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

```
<Window.Resources>
  <TemperatureLimitConverter x:Key="TemperatureLimitConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<DataTrigger Value="False">
  <DataTrigger.Binding>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TemperatureLimitConverter}">
      <Binding Path="warmed" /> 
      <Binding Path="MaxMinutes" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </DataTrigger.Binding>
<DataTrigger Value="False">
```